# Не отображаются звезды в своем ratingbare

Tags: android, ratingbar

Чудеса прям какие-то.

файл custom_rating.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star"/>

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_progres"/>

    <item
       android:id="@android:id/progress"
       android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_progres"/>

   </layer-list>
```

файл стилей style.xml

```
        <style name="CustomRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_rating</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">30dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">30dp</item>
    </style>
```

активити майн

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.forvipcommunication.myapplication.MainActivity">

<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar_news"
    android:isIndicator="true"
    style="@style/CustomRatingBar"
    android:layout_gravity="top|left"
    android:rating="5"
    android:numStars="5" />
```

Итог всей этой писанины - при любых установках любых лайаутах и т.п. показываеться ОДНА звезда в с нуля начатом проекте.

Подскажите пожалуйста почему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Косяк со штатным эмулятором. НА реальных устройствах все отображается